# How to implement socket readAll

Tags: c++, sockets, posix, epoll

I am trying to implement the `readAll` function and `readyRead` signal which expect to work the same as [QTcpSocket::readAll](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) and [QTcpSocket::readyRead](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead).

This is I tried.

Epoll event loop with the non-blocking socket

```
// below run when epoll event(EPOLLIN) is triggered
int ready_read_size;
ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &ready_read_size);
if (ready_read_size < 0) {
    // error
} else if(ready_read_size == 0) {
    // socket closed?
} else {
    // ready to read
    ready_read(fd, ready_read_size); // call the ready_read() callback
}
```

Implementation

```
typedef std::vector<uint8_t> Bytes;

Bytes read_all(int sfd, int size)
{
    Bytes buffer(size);
    int r = read(sfd, buffer.data(), size);
    if (r != size) {
        // error
    }
    return buffer;
}

void ready_read(int sfd, int size)
{
    Bytes read = read_all(sfd, size);
    //Further application process with read data... 
}
```

- Is this design correct?
- When `ready_read_size == 0`, is that same as `read(...) == 0`? means the socket has disconnected.
- Is possible that `ready_read_size != read(...)` happens?

Comment: Is possible that ready_read_size != read(...) happens?  Yes, it can happend if socket is closed just after this call : `ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &ready_read_size);` 
you will try to read on a closed socket so : `ready_read_size != read(...)` will be true.
The last call `Bytes read = read_all(sfd);` should be `Bytes read = read_all(sfd, size);` no ?

Comment: I have a reflection on the design of your program. You have chosen the **non-blocking** (asynchronous) read method. This means that the event loop will run continuously (with a scan frequency, a timer, ...).
You will therefore consume resources (CPU) even if there is nothing to read from the socket buffer.
In the continuity of my reflexion: what will happen if the buffer is empty? this case does not seem to me to be supported by your program (your second question requires a thorough verification)

Comment: To answer your second question:  
If the buffer is empty: **ready read_size = 0**  
if the socket is closed: ioctl returns an error.  
Your program requires therefore a modification at this level : `if(ready_read_size == 0) {
    // socket closed?
}`